# Issue on opening, editing and downloading a .csv file on PHP

Tags: php, csv, file-io, download

I want to open a csv file named csv.csv with PHP, then add new rows in this file, and finally download the news csv.

The content of csc.csv is:

```
name, town
name1, town1
name2, town2
name3, town3
name4, town4
```

and I want to add these rows:

```
name5, town5
name6, town6
```

I made this PHP code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


$file = fopen("csv.csv","r");
$list = array();
while(! feof($file))
  {
  $list[] = array(print_r(fgetcsv($file)));
  }
fclose($file);

$list[] = array('name5', 'town5');
$list[] = array('name6', 'town6');

outputCSV($list);

function outputCSV($list) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working code.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("csv.csv","a+");

$list = array();
$list[] = array('name5', 'town5');
$list[] = array('name6', 'town6');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($file, $fields,',');
    }

fclose($file);

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csv_".time().".csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
```

### UPDATE 1 :

for creating new file without editing existing one.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


$file = fopen("csv.csv","r");
$list = array();

while(! feof($file))
  {
      $list[] = (fgetcsv($file));
  }
fclose($file);

$list[] = array('name5', 'town5');
$list[] = array('name6', 'town6');

$list = array_filter($list);
outputCSV($list);

function outputCSV($list) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but instead of edited it, how can I download the new content?

Comment: what do you mean exactly please

Comment: for this open file with `r` mode. Get all rows in array, then merge new data in array and then write.

Comment: thanks a lot, it exactly the output I wanted, just a question though, any idea why now I have "town" instead of town, "town1" instead of town1... in the file file.csv

Comment: for this [refer example #1 from this link](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), php wrapped a string in quotes.  If it solves your problem then kindly consider to `Mark question as Solved` and `Vote Up`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and all your explanations!